# RequestQueue in Volley

Tags: android, performance, android-volley

Can Someone give me some direction on how **RequestQueue** behaves in case of the situation of query failure.

Is the query is **retried** or it **moves to the end** of the queue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on the RetryPolicy as to how the request is retried.

Comment: Is there any 'by-default' policy?

Comment: Yes, DefaultRetryPolicy.  http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nl.stevenhack.volley/library/1.0.2/com/android/volley/DefaultRetryPolicy.java

Comment: @Submersed, I am sorry if i am wrong, but it doesn't explain what happen after max retry. Is the request dropped permanently? and is this source of Google's volley?

Comment: You'd get some sort of callback in your onErrorResponse depending on why the request failed after the maximum retry attempts have occurred.

Comment: @Submersed, ok got it, it was throwing error in the code itself, thanks

Comment: Np, I'll consolidate my comments into an answer if this answered the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Request is retried dependent on the RetryPolicy attached to the request.  If you don't provide a RetryPolicy, the volley helper class DefaultRetryPolicy is used.

Once a Request is attempted the maximum number of "attempts" provided by the retry policy, you'll get an onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) callback whose VolleyError type will be dependent on the cause of the Request's failure.